# why is this white area appearing in my modal window?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALoKj.png)

i can set the width with with css but the source from which i created this code dosent seem to have this problem
here is the code:

```
<div class="info-box visible-md visible-lg">
                        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo accent-4"href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="myBtn">login</a>
                    </div>

    <!--modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog blue-grey darken-4 card-panel">
            <div class="modal-content blue-grey darken-4">
                <div class="modal-header blue-grey darken-4">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><center><img src="images/.png" alt="" style="height: 90px;"></center></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body blue-grey darken-4">
                    <form action="" method="POST">      
                        <h3 class="center">Login</h3>

                         <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
                         </div>

                          <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                            <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Enter password">
                          </div>

                         <p class="right">Dont have an account? <a href="#signup" class="modal-trigger">Sign up</a></p>
                         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn left col s12 indigo accent-4">

                         <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer blue-grey darken-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn modal-close indigo accent-4" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the CSS as well.

Answer (score -1):

materialize.min.css and bootstrap.css had conflicting value for modal that was causing the issue